# Unity 2dclicker game is not working when i run it

Tags: unity-game-engine

** "Problem solved" **
Today 14 june, i opened my unity project, its a 2d "clicker" game. When i pressed play the game loaded but i cant interact with anything, and i cant hear the music or sounds, also if i change the resolution, the camera behave weird.
If i set active/deactivate any gameObjects it doesn't show in the game view neither in the scene.Its like the game view is frozen.
All this happens when i run play. If i stop everithing is fine, i can modify everything, and if i change the resolution, the camera works correctly.
What can i do? Yesterday it worked perfectly. Here are some screenshoots.
To whoever takes his time to reply, THANK YOU.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YtZx.png)

ADDITIONAL INFO: i build the game and exported to my phone, its working ok. The problem is with unity i think. –

*UPDATE*
Im the stupidest person ever. I solved my problem. IN CASE ANYONE HAS THE SAME PROBLEM, all i had to do, after 2 days of trying  to make things work, i found that i had activated "Pause on error" in my console, i dont know how i activated that. As i had in one of my script to send error message in my console, the game automatically paused from the start.
Sorry for my grammar.

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFO: i build the game and exported to my phone, its working ok. The problem is with unity i think.

Comment: You should provide some code and if you want to add additional info to your question, it's better to edit the question itself rather than posting the information in a comment.

Comment: I understand Don Andre. Its my first time asking. What code should i provide? 2 days ago,before i colsed unity, everything worked fine. And yesterday when i opened unity this happened. I closed and reopened unity multiple times but nothing...